# USB keyboard, unaffected by settings, repeating keys when held together

Tags: keyboard, macos, usb

*Key Repeat* and *Delay Until Repeat* settings work fine and are immediately applied for the MacBook keyboard in *TextEdit*, but have no effect on the USB keyboard - even after reboot.

If I hold *hi*, the result is *hhi* via the USB keyboard. Further, if I hold *hit*, the result is *hhihit*.

Another example, if I hold *ca*, the result is *cac* via the USB keyboard. Further, if I hold *cat*, the result is *cactac*. So different keys seems to give different behavior.

Any idea how to disable the repeating letters upon holding on the USB keyboard? Since it makes it difficult to type quickly. Also a bonus would be to have the keyboard settings applied to the USB keyboard.

- TeckNet Kraken LED Illuminated Gaming Keyboard
- macOS Sierra 10.12.3
- MacbBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011)

Comment: Are you able to test this with a more standard usb keyboard to see whether it has the same behavior as your gaming keyboard?

Comment: Finally got hold of a neighbours' old sticky keyboard (ES) loaded with dog hairs even after cleaning - functions normally w/o this issue! Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @tom-gewecke's suggestion! Trying a different keyboard worked, functioning normally without this issue.

So it seems to be a compatibility issue between the aforementioned keyboard and OS, possibly other versions of both.